# use filter function to filter #t symbols

Tags: filter, scheme

I want to filter out all the true expressions using the filter function:

```
(filter '#t '(#t #t #f #f #t))
```

this is the error i am getting :

filter: contract violation
  expected: (any/c . -> . any/c)
  given: #t

Comment: The first argument to `filter` is supposed to be a function, not the element to remove.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If Barmar's answer worked for you, do consider upvoting it (since currently I'm the only upvoter). ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I probably will, but I would like to see a bit more clarification about what's the actual programming language (and version) being used here.  As the comments on that answer point out, there's some difference between Racket and various versions of Scheme in whether `remove` and `filter`are defined and, if they are, what they take as arguments.

Comment: @JY2k What particular language are you using?  Are you using some version of Racket, or one of the various RNRS Schemes?  This will be important in determining what definitions are available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` is used when you want to run a function on each element, and keep the ones where it returns a true value. If you just want to remove a specific value, use `remove` (or `remq` or `remv`, depending on the equivalence predicate you want to use):

```
(remove #t '(#t #t #f #f #t))
```

Comment: This removes the first occurrence only. Use (remove* '(#t) '(#t #t #f #f #t)) instead.

Comment: @uselpa I don't see that in [R6RS List Utilities](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html)

Comment: Interesting... I looked in the Racket docs, this procedure seems to be different from R6RS.

Comment: @uselpa That's what _Racket's_ [`remove`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/list..rkt)._remove))) does. The SRFI-1 [`remove`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#remove) actually is a filter (it takes a predicate and removes _all_ the matches).